# How to use comma separated values in a cell, as parameters in formula (PivotTable specifically)?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a formula that pulls data from PivotTable and sums up according to ID:

```
=SUM(GETPIVOTDATA("Value",$A$3,"AccounID",{5637855, 6839652, 5839670}))
```

I would like to use the same formula but with a reference:

```
=SUM(GETPIVOTDATA("Value",$A$3,"AccounID",A1))
```

When `A1` is: `5637855`, `6839652`, `5839670`.

In this case if there is one ID or 10 IDs - it will be the same formula and I can only add an ID in the cell A1.

I am sure that it is possible somehow with Macro, but I want a simple way (since macros in my company are restricted).

I found a few workarounds with `SUMPRODUCT` and range of cells, but this solution is not practical in my case.

Comment: Does this give you any ideas? https://superuser.com/q/249437/127429

Comment: I already saw similar solutions as well as with range of cells (which work great), but in my case it not useful. the only possible solution is the one that I want (if it exists)

Answer (score 0):

Use this array formula

```
=SUM(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Value",$A$3,"AccounID",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN($A$1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99))),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

All the `A1` refer to the cell in which the string is found, ***EXCEPT*** the first one in the ROW argument.  Leave that as `A1` change all the others to the cell in which the string can be found.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Option2:**

*if someone doesn't have the cell `A1` restriction`*

Create a table (use format as table) with the `IDs` you want to sum:

```
[criteria]
| 5637855|
| 6839652|
| 5839670|
```

[image]

Then replace in your formula with the range from your table `criteria` like:

`=SUM(GETPIVOTDATA("Value",$D$1,"AccounID",Table1[criteria]))`

[image]

and activate the formula as an array with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> depending your Excel version.

[image]

If you highlight `Table1[criteria]` in the formula and press <kbd>F9</kbd> you will see that the value it is getting is `{5637855, 6839652, 5839670}`.

Comment: OP specifically stated that they can only use A1 `I can only add an ID in the cell A1`  Then again reiterated this in the comments.

Comment: How helpful would this answer be if all the images disappeared?

Comment: @miken32 I don't know what are you talking about the images still there. Try in another browser...

Comment: They're there now, but what if they aren't in the future? Or what if a user were visually impaired? Image-only answers are no more helpful than link-only answers. Edit your answer to include the formulas and other relevant data in the text of the answer and it will be much more helpful.